# What does "we know will" mean?

Tags: meaning

> XX's
>   deep experience makes them a partner we know
>   will benefit from the innovative services we
>   provide for our clients

XX is a name of a company, and does it mean "XX's deep experience makes them a partner that we know that we will be able to improve innovative service we provide for our clients"?

Comment: Read 'Partner' as 'Client' and you might find it easier to understand.  Note that THEY are 'Benefiting FROM' those services.  Assuming XX is the 'Partner'

Comment: @JeffUK  It's still confusing.. Then does it mean "With XX's deep experience, we know that clients will benefit from the innovative services we provide for our clients."?

Comment: Who is XX, the context matters, they could be 'the company' or 'the partner'

Comment: @JeffUK XX is a partner of "we".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question is *yes*, "we know will..." in this context could also be read as "*that* we know will..."

However, the whole sentence doesn't really make sense if the purpose of it is to sell or advertise the services of "XX". As it is written, it means that the party benefitting *is* 'XX', not their partners or clients. Shouldn't it imply that XX's experience will benefit their partners? Are "partners" not the same as "clients" in this context? Also, "deep experience" is not particularly idiomatic.

I think the sentence should say something like:

> XX's extensive experience guarantees our partners will benefit from the innovative services we provide.

If I have misunderstood please provide more context including who you represent, or whose perspective the statement is coming from.

Comment: I think this makes more sense if you think of a 'partnership' being something like an affiliate scheme, a franchise, or a 'software partnership' (xx sells our product to our mutual clients).